# Override PermissionMap in symfony 3.2

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I need to create my own permissionmap in Symfony3.
I updated Symfony2.8 to 3.2 and now my own PermissionMap class is not being used anymore.

In 2.8 I could do:

```
parameters:
    security.acl.permission.map.class: UserBundle\Permission\PermissionMap
```

This is not working in 3.2 anymore.
Anyone know how I can use my custom PermissionMap in 3.2 ?

Comment: Have you check the changelog of 3.0, 3.1 & 3.2 ? The change that broke your config must be listed in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parameter `security.acl.permission.map.class` has been removed in Symfony 3. Now you should decorate the `security.acl.permission.map` service instead:

```
# config.yml
services:
    security.acl.permission.map:
        class: UserBundle\Permission\PermissionMap
```

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14070/files#diff-cb370dc553bc7472fa2594a068a94404 for more details about these changes.